# Is there a way to submit an app to AppStore from MacBook Pro 2011?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, operating-system

I can't run my Xcode because it requires an update. I can't update Xcode because it requires at least OS Mojave (I'm currently on High Sierra 10.13.6). I can't update to Mojave because it doesn't support my MacBook Pro 2011. 
I went to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and currently downloading Xcode 9.4.1, but I'm not sure if I'll be able to submit an app to AppStore from it.

Is buying a new Mac the only option or what else could I do?

Comment: you can try using this patch http://dosdude1.com/mojave/.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, All the apps uploaded to the AppStore required to be built using Xcode 10 and Starting April, 2020, all apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with Xcode 11. Xcode 11 requires macOS Mojave 10.14.3 or later.

check https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/